# MemoryError using numeric range as dict index (Inefficient)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a need to define numeric ranges as a dictionary index such as:

```
SCHEDULE = {
    (0, 5000): 1,
    (5001, 22500): 2,
    (22501, 999999999): 3
}
```

I search it by this function:

```
def range_index(table, val):
    new_table = {k: v for tup, v in table.items() for k in range(tup[0], tup[1]+1)}
    return new_table.get(int(val))  # int() is used to deal with floats.
```

which works good as long as the range isn't too big. The last entry in `SCHEDULE` which is `999999999` causes Python to throw `MemoryError`. If I decrease it to a smaller number, it's fine.

This obviously means we are building this whole table from the ranges. How can this be re-worked so that the entire ranges aren't enumerated for each search?

Comment: It makes no sense to create a dict each time you do a search.  It would be much faster to search your table directly.  A dict only has speed advantages if you use it multiple times after creating it.  It's also obvious from the nested for loops in the comprehension that it's fully expanding the product of the ranges, creating a distinct dict entry for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for an order-based data structure, not a hash-based data structure like a dict. Hashes are good for equality. They don't do range tests.

Your table should be a pair of lists. The first is sorted and represents range endpoints, and the second represents values associated with each range:

```
# I don't have enough information to give these better names.
endpoints = [0, 5001, 22501, 1000000000]
values = [1, 2, 3]
```

To find a value, perform a binary search for the index in the first list and look up the corresponding value in the second. You can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for the binary search:

```
import bisect

def lookup(endpoints, values, key):
    index = bisect.bisect_right(endpoints, key) - 1
    if index < 0 or index >= len(values):
        raise KeyError('{!r} is out of range'.format(key))
    return values[index]
```

Comment: What say you of Austin's method?

Comment: @xendi: It's a brute-force search, and essentially the same idea as Amadan's method. It still beats your original code, at least.

Comment: I choose this as most correct. If one wants to make it prettier, just put `endpoints` and `values` in a dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `next` on generator with a default value as 0 to handle `StopIteration`:

```
def range_index(table, val):
    return next((v for k, v in table.items() if k[0] <= int(val) <= k[1]), 0)
```

This uses the usual less than, greater than checks to find the range of `val` and get the value corresponding.

**Advantages**:

- No new dictionary creation for every search.
- Exits immediately when the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `SCHEDULE` and return the first value where `val` is in the associated range.

```
category = next(category
                for (start, stop), category in SCHEDULE.items()
                if val in range(start, stop + 1))
```

It would be a bit faster if you started off with a dict of ranges, not of tuples. It would be even faster if you made `SCHEDULE` into a binary tree, and did a binary search on it instead of a linear one. But this is good enough for majority of cases.

This assumes your `SCHEDULE` is exhaustive, and you'll get a `StopIteration` error if you submit a `val` that is not covered by any of the ranges, to signify a programmer error. If you wish an `else` value, put it as a second parameter to `next`, after wrapping the first parameter in parentheses.

Comment: You can't binary search a heap; you need a fully sorted list for that.